# Angular New Date ()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app with angular date picker. It parses the current date and time. However I need to parse the current date and default time (10:00am) and (18:00pm) in two timepicker. Below is my controller script. (Not all, I just copied what I believe is related).

```
reserv_for_boat = [];
$scope.ship = {
  fromtimeValue: cur_date,
  totimeValue: cur_date
};
$scope.cur_date = cur_date.getFullYear()+" 年 " + (parseInt(cur_date.getMonth()) + 1)+" 月" + cur_date.getDate()+" 日";
$scope.cur_date_date = cur_date;
$scope.dayval = dds[cur_date.getDay()];
```

I want to display yyyy-mm-dd 10:00 AM   and yyyy-mm-dd 18:00PM

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)? It's a mature js library to make life easier dealing with date and time. so that you don't need to write verbose codes to do simple stuff.